# Model::operator =(cv::dnn::dnn4_v20210301::Model &&)' : is not a special member function which can be defaulted

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to OpenCV. I was using VS express 2013 for a c++ application that will just load and display some images.

This is the code that I wrote

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"
#include"opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(){
    cout << "hello world";  
    Mat image1 = imread("F:/data/S1.jpg")
    imshow("first image",image1);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I am running it I am getting this error :

```
7   IntelliSense: invalid type for defaulted assignment operator    
Error   3   error C3646: 'noexcept' : unknown override specifier    
Error   4   error C3646: 'noexcept' : unknown override specifier    
Error   6   error C3646: 'noexcept' : unknown override specifier    
Error   1   error C2610: 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20210301::Model::Model(cv::dnn::dnn4_v20210301::Model &&)' : is not a special member function which can be defaulted   
Error   2   error C2610: 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20210301::Model &cv::dnn::dnn4_v20210301::Model::operator =(cv::dnn::dnn4_v20210301::Model &&)' : is not a special member function which can be defaulted  
Error   5   error C2610: 'cv::cuda::GpuMatND &cv::cuda::GpuMatND::operator =(cv::cuda::GpuMatND &&)' : is not a special member function which can be defaulted
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: you seem to be running with C++03 or earlier, `noexcept` is available since C++11

Comment: Did you get a version of opencv binaries that is compatible with your 8 year old compiler? Binaries for Visual Studio 2015 to 2019 will be incompatible, Since these versions have binary compatible with 2015 to 2019 but no other version of Visual Studio. Related: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 0):

As people have pointed out in the comments, Visual C++ Express 2013 is a very old compiler which barely supports a fraction of C++11 (probably only C++03 or less). Therefore, it is complaining about the `noexcept` exception specification. The second error may be a side effect of the first. The only way around this would be to use a newer compiler, which means you may also have to get updated builds of your project's dependencies.